# Debug countif and autofill in excel VBA, criteria doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba, range, criteria, countif

I will need a function to count the number of each item in column J and show the result on column K. But this code I show below keep saying that the criteria part RC[-2] is wrong. After the countif function, I will need it to be able to autofill in whatever lines are given so that I can apply this code to other files as well.

I used Macro to generate some code to start. And also try this earlier:
paste_countPTD = Worksheetfunction.CountIf(paste_conPTD,RC[-2]).

The criteria part seemed wrong.

```
Dim paste_conPTD As Range
Set paste_conYTD = Range("J2:J" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

Range("K1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Count_PTD"
Range("K2").Worksheetfunction.countif(paste_conPTD,RC[-2])
```

I appreciate any suggestion to make this code works. To do the countif for a column and autofill the formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
Dim paste_conPTD As Range
Set paste_conYTD = Range("J2:J" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

Range("K1") = "Count_PTD"

Dim iRng as Range   

For each iRng in paste_conPTD

    iRng.Offset(0,1) = Worksheetfunction.Countif(paste_conPTD, iRng)

Next iRng
```

To give you some notes, we need to *iterate* over each cells in the `paste_conYTD` range, that is where `iRng` comes in. We can't tell Excel like `paste_conYTD = <some formula>` and assume Excel knows we want it to compute for each cells using the formula. Excel iteration comes in a few ways, we can choose one that is easiest to apply based on scenario.

- `For each ... in ... Next`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement

- `For ... Next`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement

- `Do... Loop`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doloop-statement

- `While... Wend`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/whilewend-statement

Answer (score 0):

If you want the actual formula in the cells try this.
    Dim paste_conPTD As Range

```
    Set paste_conYTD = Range("J2:J" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    Range("K1").Value = "Count_PTD"
    paste_conYTD.Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(" & paste_conYTD.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",RC[-2])"
```